# No notifications of new voicemails on iPhone despite being able to play them

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, voicemail

I am not receiving notification of new voicemails on my iPhone 4 (model A1349).  The voicemails are available and I can listen to them if I check but I receive no notification when a new one arrives.

This has been a problem for many months but I've finally missed enough information that I'd like to try to fix it.

I've found suggestions on various websites to use "Reset Network Settings".  I haven't tried this yet because I don't know the full consequences and I'd rather not disrupt the rest of my phone service.

Comment: Resetting network settings is not a bad idea: the only thing it does is reset your WiFi and Bluetooth connections (so you will have to type in WiFi network passwords again and repair bluetooth devices) and cycle on/off your connection to cell networks (harmless but could fix issues).

Comment: Have you tried more basic troubleshooting (toggling on/off airplane mode, turning WiFi Calling on or off, restarting your device)?

Comment: And can you ensure that the Phone app is allowed to send you notifications (including banners, including show on lock screen) in `Settings` -> `Notifications` -> `Phone`?

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and "Reset Network Settings" and then restarted the phone.  The behavior seems the same (call from another phone, don't answer, leave voicemail, notification of missing call on target phone but no notification of voicemail).  The phone has `Settings` -> `Notification Center` with an `include` section that has `Phone` beneath it.  I'm not sure if that's the same as what you're referring to.  There doesn't seem to be anything named just `Notifications` in `Settings`.

Comment: Ok. If you go to Settings -> Notification Center -> Phone (or Settings -> scroll way down to Phone -> Notifications) make sure it's allowed to send you banner notifications and make sure `Show on Lock Screen` is enabled.

Comment: `Show on Lock Screen` is enabled.  `Phone` is set to allow alert notifications.  That seems like it should work as well as banner notifications?  I also tried restarting the phone and toggling wifi and airplane mode again, just to see, but to no apparent effect.

Comment: Try "resetting" the voicemail: Open Phone then go to the dial pad. Using the traditional method, press and hold the number 1 key to access your voicemail. You may have to enter your voicemail password. Listen to all your voicemail messages, then once you are through, you should end the call. Finally, leave a voicemail message from another phone. This time, you should get a voicemail notification.

Comment: Also try plugging your device into iTunes, then allow any software updates or carrier version updates to happen. A carrier update could fix this.

Comment: Those methods are from [here](https://www.iskysoft.com/article/iphone-voicemail-notification.html).

Comment: And if those two methods fail, contact your carrier's customer support, they may well be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Recently upgraded from iphone 5s to iphone 8 and also changed providers, had 5s call forwarded to new iphone 8 for a month to be certain i would be satisfied with coverage ect. Everything wad 100%, voicemail worked fine. After cancelling old service provider my voicemail stopped showing notifications but were accessable, just didn’t know i had any. After hours of tech support and reading different forums I decided to backup my old phone to my computer and restore to new phone. Now everything is working fine.
Hope it helps someone.